# MobileFirst analytics trace log showing wlSkinLoaderChecksum = null

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

In MobileFirst analytics , we get below trace logs frequently :

**Package**  WL_INIT

**Level**  Trace

**Message**

`nit params:{
 appVersionPref = "1.9.1"; freeSpace = 7347441664;
 wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)"; wlSkinName = default;
 }`

What can be the reason for checksum to be `null`?

Comment: Are you using skins?

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_developing_application_skins.html?lang=en

if not and the application runs ok, I think you can ignore this 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be a checksum value, if you are not using any other skin in your application other than the default one. If you are not using skins, then it is OK for the value to be null.